# get time in h:i format from javascript GMT date format

Tags: javascript

I am working in JavaScript. I have date in below format:

```
Tue Sep 18 2012 01:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

I want to display it in below format

```
'Y-m-d h:i:s'
```

OR

How to get time only from `(Tue Sep 18 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))` this format in JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `Date` object you can do this:

```
var timeString = myDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (myDate.getMonth()+1) + '-'
+ myDate.getDate() + ' ' + myDate.getHours() + ':' + myDate.getMinutes() + ':' 
+ myDate.getSeconds();
```

If you have a `String` just do this before:

```
var myDate = new Date('Tue Sep 18 2012 01:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) ');
```

Comment: It Worked like butter :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are several good libraries out there that help you work with dates (e.g. [date.js](http://momentjs.com/), [moment.js](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs)).

Since you mentioned in one of the comments that you don't want to include additional js files, there are also smaller versions (e.g. [dateFormat](http://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js)) which you could easily copy-paste or adapt into your current code.

If you really want to roll your own date formatter instead of using existing ones, you can simply build your own string using the methods provided by the Date object.

Here's a quick example:

```
function getMyDateFormat(date) {
    var d = date ? new Date(date) : new Date;
    var dt = [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay()].join("-"),
        tm = [d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds()].join(":");
    return dt + " " + tm;
}
```

Example usage:

```
str = getMyDateFormat();  // default (current datetime)
// 2012-8-4 14:3:22

str = getMyDateFormat("Tue Sep 18 2012 01:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time"); 
// output (in my locale): 2012-8-1 21:0:0 

var now = new Date();
str = getMyDateFormat(now);  // using a date object
// output: 2012-8-4 14:3:22
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6ByFN/

And here's a variant that pads the single digit values with 0's: http://jsfiddle.net/6ByFN/1/

Answer (score 0):

Moment.js is a nice JS library that can help with parsing and formatting dates.

http://momentjs.com/

Comment: for this  have to include moment library in my code. Can't include file. I have to do it without including any file.

Comment: Out of interest, why can you not include the library?

Comment: Are you working with a js date object or just a string? (because you can just pull the values you want out of the date object). If you have a string you can parse that into a date object using new Date((Date.parse(*your string*))) and then pull whatever values you want out it into a string.